# Azure IoT Hub - Implement key rollover using the C SDK

Tags: azure-iot-hub

Are about to implement support for key rollover, swapping primary/secondary key up on connection failure related to bad credentials.

The plan is to use the ConnectionStatusCallback and check the "IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_STATUS_REASON_VALUES" for "IOTHUB_CLIENT_CONNECTION_BAD_CREDENTIAL" and then trigger a swap.

But to swap the key, do i need to tear-down the IoTHubClient or can the key be swapped on the fly?

We are using the latest C SDK tagged "2018-07-11" and the LL APIs.

Comment: Connection failure commonly can't be caused by the device key except you refresh the key at service back end. Can you show the error message of the connection failure in order to find out the underlying reason?

Comment: Main reson is to move devices between IoT Hubs remote. Suggested procedure is to update one of the keys to the destination IoT Hub, update the IoT Hub endpoint. Reboot the device and swap primary/secondary key depending on ConnectionStatusCallback message. When connected update the remaining key so that both keys are from the destination hub.

Answer (score 0):

> Main reson is to move devices between IoT Hubs remote.

I assume you are talking about remote move devices from one hub to another hub without edit code on devices.

The simplest case is that the destination iot hub has the same name with source iot hub. Otherwise, you need send the destination hub name to the devices. Of course, two hubs has the same name can't exist in the same subscription.

I describe what I think about working steps:

I assume there are two hubs, one is **hub1** that is source hub and another is **hub2** that is the destination hub. Take device1 for example, it has the primary key: **key1** and secondary key: **key2**.

[image]